# Image name on download javascript

Tags: javascript, image

i need a JavaScript to download a group of images.
It should download some like this:

```
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg....
```

but i get default file name:

```
5cEDZLQ.jpg
5Npv209.jpg
5FgtD69.jpg...
```

here my function to download:

```
function SaveToDisk(fileURL, fileName) {
        var save = document.createElement('a');
        save.href = fileURL;
        save.target = '_blank';
        save.download = fileName;

        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        save.dispatchEvent(event);
        window.webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    }
```

tried various ways, but always download with the default name

Comment: which browser you tried?

Comment: Chrome v38.0.2125.104 m

Answer (score 0):

Well is a long time but here is the solve.

Dowload the image/file using XMLHttpRequest and pass the result to the function saveAs from [**FileSaver.js**](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/272px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png';
var name = 'Google Logo.png';
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        console.log( ((e.loaded / e.total) * 100) + '%');
    }
};
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var file = this.response;
        saveAs(file, name);
        console.log('File Saved!!!')
    }
};
xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    alert("Error " + e.target.status + " occurred while receiving the document.");
};
xhr.send();
```